# samba Ubuntu client slow, Windows client fast

Tags: samba4

I have a ubuntu 20.04 server with default samba installation, and a ubuntu 20.04 client mounting the share with:

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx/share    /home/user1/share     cifs username=user2,noauto,rw,users   0 0
```

I try to uncompress a 60Mb file from server in the same server folder, and it is painfully slow (~15 minutes).
I checked server configuration, but I created a win10 virtual machine on client, connected to the share, and the operation takes less than a minute; so my problem should be on client.

Any idea of how to optimize de mount?

Thanks